# How to check if an event was prevented

Tags: javascript, events, dom, preventdefault

In JavaScript, how can I check if an event (like keypress) was prevented with `e.preventDefault()`? I'm not using jQuery.

Answer (score 20):

You can check the event object's [`defaultPrevented`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.defaultPrevented) property (which is a boolean indicating if `preventDefault` was ever called for that particular event object).

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @Jim From your event listener, console.log the event.  For instance: `document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { console.log(e)})`.  One of `e`s properties will be `defaultPrevented`.

Comment: use event.isDefaultPrevented()

Answer (score 5):

By the way, if you're looking for ***why*** `defaultPrevented` is `true` (i.e. who called `preventDefault()`), this post was super helpful: https://hackernoon.com/finding-that-pesky-listener-thats-hijacking-your-event-javascript-b590593f2a83

To summarize:

1. Inspect the event's element in Chrome.
2. Click on the `Event Listeners` tab in the side panel.
3. You'll see all the listeners. If you click on them they'll open in the Sources tab and you should see a `preventDefault()` call.